# I want to set navigation color to different colors for each VC

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I already have code where it will change the VC nav bar to the color of my choice but then it also changes the "home" nav bar to that color so I think I will need to have if statements to check which ones should be colored.

How do I write "if this view controller then this color. else blah blah blah?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to add code in each view controller's `viewWillAppear` method that updates the nav bar appearance as needed. This way, as each view controller appears, it sets how things should look.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Update colors as needed for this view controller
}
```

Comment: It works! Though there is a split second where the main one remains the color of the previous VC after I hit the back button.. I'll deal with that another time though. Thank you

Comment: Then add the line to viewDidLoad() method.

Comment: @Ray_Soham No, `viewDidLoad` is the wrong place to update the colors for this use case.